# Book about saber-toothed tigers trapped in a cave in the USA

Tags: story-identification, books

I recall a book about some saber-toothed tigers that were trapped in a cave in the USA and either were frozen or just kept living generation after generation until modern times, but I can't remember the name of the book or the author.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you read this?